# Google Cast Icon does not show up for some cast devices

Tags: android, casting, chromecast, google-cast

I am implementing Google Cast in my application and the integration is based on the Cast Companion Library. I have found that the cast icon does not show up in some situations, for certain people.

It shows up on my chromecast, which is brand new (and has no whitelistings), and so far only one other user's device. It does not show up on multiple devices belonging to other users, nor on one user's ADT-1.

I am using a published app, not in developer mode, so this has nothing to do with whitelistings.

I have found so far, that every instance where the icon does not show up, it also does not show up if the user's try the CastVideos app found here :

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.sample.cast.refplayer

Which also uses the Cast Companion Library.

The only app I have found that ALWAYS shows up in all cases, is YouTube, so I am curious what magical integration they are using.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this, or prevent a similar situation in the future? Is it related to versioning of Google Play Services?

Comment: The CastVideos app you provided a link to is not an official app; you may consider downloading the source of that app yourself from our github repo: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android. Try that and let us know if that works for you or not.Make sure you are on the latest play services when you compile the app.

Comment: Sure, I can do that when I get to a proper internet connection. Is the contention that cast may just stop working at anytime if google decides to upgrade play services? Kind of unfortunate...

Comment: The idea is that if there is a bug that is an older version of Play Services that has been fixed in later versions, then you need to have the fix if it affects your issue.